# SQL divide issue with nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count, window-functions

I have simple table1

```
Catergory
 A
 A
 A
 B
 B
```

Need result in percent by each group (group A = 3 (a)/5 (total A and B ) and same with group B

```
percent Catergory
 .6       A
 .4       B
```

My query will have issue 
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'A' to data type int

```
with total as
    (select count(catergory) as totalcount, catergory as single
    from table2
    group by catergory )

select single/ totalcount from total
```

Can you correct the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions for this:

```
select
    1.0 * count(*) / sum(count(*)) over() ratio,
    category
from mytable
group by category
```

Comment: @user13636604: `cast(1.0 * count(*) / sum(count(*)) over() as decimal(3, 2))`

Comment: No, it does not round up

Comment: @user13636604 . . . This would seem to do what you are asking for.  I don't understand your comments.